# Use .htaccess to redirect a number then extension differently than a number underscore letter followed by extension

Tags: htaccess, 301-redirect

How to do this with regular expression?

```
Old -> New
http://www.example.com/1.html   -> http://www.example.com/dir/1.html
http://www.example.com/2.html   -> http://www.example.com/dir/2.html
http://www.example.com/3.asp    -> http://www.example.com/dir/3.html
http://www.example.com/4.asp    -> http://www.example.com/dir/4.html
http://www.example.com/4_a.html -> http://www.example.com/dir/sub/4-a.html
http://www.example.com/4_b.html -> http://www.example.com/dir/sub/4-b.html
```

I've tried this:

```
Redirect 301 /1.html http://www.example.com/dir/1.html 
Redirect 301 /2.html http://www.example.com/dir/2.html 
Redirect 301 /3.asp http://www.example.com/dir/3.html 
Redirect 301 /4.asp http://www.example.com/dir/4.html 
Redirect 301 /4_a.html http://www.example.com/dir/sub/4-a.html 
Redirect 301 /4_b.html http://www.example.com/dir/sub/4-b.html
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather more general solution, so in that respect it might not be what you are after, but it should redirect the URLs in your question.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(\d)\.(html|asp)$ /dir/$1.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(\d)_([a-z])\.html$ /dir/sub/$1-$2.html [R=301,L]
```

The first `RewriteRule` will match any single digit URL eg. `1.html` or `7.asp` and redirect to `/dir/1.html` or `/dir/7.html` respectively. The `$1` backreference matches the first parenthesised sub pattern in the pattern that is matched.

The second `RewriteRule` matches a URL that contains a single digit followed by an underscore and then a single lowercase letter. The underscore is replaced with a hyphen in the redirect. eg. `6_g.html` is redirected to `/dir/sub/6-g.html`.

---

#### Alternative (more restrictive) version

If a more restrictive version is required that only matches the specific URLs stated in the question then you could do something like the following instead. Although it is arguably more "complex"...

```
RewriteRule ^([12])\.html|([34])\.asp$ /dir/$1$2.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(4)_([ab])\.html$ /dir/sub/$1-$2.html [R=301,L]
```

The first rule would perhaps be easier to read if it was split into two. The two backreferences `$1` and `$2` in the first rule are mutually exclusive, when one is set, the other is empty, hence the presence of both in the *substitution* string.

If you are not already using mod_rewrite elsewhere in your `.htaccess` then mod_alias `RedirectMatch` directives may be preferable, although this does make the regex marginally more complex because of the slash prefix that needs to be matched...

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(?:([12])\.html|([34])\.asp)$ /dir/$1$2.html
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(4)_([ab])\.html$ /dir/sub/$1-$2.html
```

Comment: Why the neg vote? Is there anything wrong with the code/answer posted? How can it be improved? Having tested this code myself, it does appear to solve the OPs problem in a more compact, efficient manner than stated in the question, using a regex.

Comment: This will cover the examples.   Some variations might be appropriate if the examples are over-simplified.  `\d+` rather than `\d` to match numbers that are more than one digit.    A [condition to prevent redirecting from files that actually exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647028/rewriterule-only-if-directory-or-file-does-not-exists). `(html|asp)` might be appropriate in both rules than than just the first.  `[a-z]+` instead of `(html|asp)` to match any extension at all rather than just the two used in the examples.

Answer (score -1):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ 
RewriteRule ^1\.html$ "http\:\/\/example\.com\/dir\/1\.html" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^1_a\.html$ "http\:\/\/example\.com\/dir\/sub\/1\-a\.html" [R=301,L]

RewriteOptions inherit
```

That should work

Comment: is it possible to use like     `RewriteRule ^((1|2)\.html|(3|4)\.asp)$ dir/$1.html [R=301, L]` ?

Comment: I wouldn't be able to tell you. Just copy that whole code and change what you need for each redirect. That's how i have in my websites. I also added the code for the one with a - on it. It's a bit trickier. That should work with no problems, just make your changes.

Comment: @guisasso: The reason for using mod_rewrite and a regex, as opposed to a mod_alias redirect, is presumably to simplify the solution. Your answer does the complete opposite.

Comment: Perhaps i know a lot less about the subject than i thought i did. Just trying to help.

Comment: @guisasso: No worries, we are all learning :). Just a few points about the code you have posted that rang some bells... **1.** No need to check against HTTP_HOST unless we are dealing with multiple domains, which doesn't seem to be the case here. **2.** No need to escape (forward) slashes, hyphens and colons in the RewriteRule substitution as they have no special meaning in the context they are used. **3.** No need to surround the RewriteRule substitution in double quotes.

Comment: Wow, interesting how syntax differences don't really make the code not work. Usually anything as simple as a " will make something not work in any language. Huh.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I came up with:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^((1|2)\.html|(3|4)\.asp)$ /dir/$1.html [R=301,L]
  RewriteRule ^(4_([a-b]))\.html$ /dir/sub/$1.html [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Do you not need a more general solution? Your solution would seem to work just for the 6 redirects you mention in your question. If this is the case then you could argue that your original `Redirect`s are the preferred solution.

Comment: Actually, your solution does not appear to work - have you tried it?! `$1` matches the first parenthesised sub pattern, which will be `1.html` or `2.html` or `3.asp` or `4.asp`, you then append `.html` which becomes `/dir/1.html.html`. I'll add an answer...

Comment: ...and the second rule fails to convert `_` (underscore) in the source URL to `-` (hyphen) in the destination.